# Can I stop Photoshop from asking for interlaced option when saving a PNG format?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I never want my PNGs to be interlaced. So I wish I could set a bunch of option defaults in the application so that I am saving time when outputting a lot of images as PNG over the course of a day working in Photoshop.

Does anyone know if this is possible in Photoshop without using Actions OR the Save-for-Web option?

Comment: .. in fact .. how about having default settings for all Save-as outputs.

Comment: Why are you against Save for Web? The files are much smaller and the interlaced option can be saved.

Comment: I'm not concerned with file size of the image since they get put through a compositor at a later stage ... Save for web optimizes the image .. I want to keep all the original data.

Comment: Basically, then, the answer is NO it is not possible to make Photoshop quit asking, right?

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if Adobe uses their own products. It gets annoying after the 3rd or 4th time. Still no "don't ask" checkbox for PNG Format Options in 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not getting the problem. Any settings you use in Save As are sticky for any particular format. They become the default until you change them. Non-interlaced *is* the default for png.

If you're trying to save time, though, why in the world would you *not* set up an Action and assign a keyboard shortcut to it? No mouse clicks needed, just hit one key combo and your file is saved as a png.

If you *really* want to save time, don't save out from individual PSDs at all. Set up the Action and do the pngs all at once using `Batch...` from Bridge, or use [Dr. Brown's Services](http://russellbrown.com/scripts.html) (Image Processor Pro -- scroll down the page).

When you record an action, or more properly, when you run it, you have the option to override the Open and Save locations. Droplets allow you to automate this to the max, so you can just drag a droplet onto an image and have the action run. See [this help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7427a.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7425a) for the details.

Here are the necessary settings, from an Action I created for a client project. It resets the aspect ratio on some video frames (TIFFs) and saves them back to the same folder as jpegs. The original recording was done saving back to the original folder. Here's the Action Panel entry. Note that dialogs are turned off:

[image: Action Panel]

Here's the Batch dialog, for running the Action inside Photoshop (also works from Bridge).

[image: Batch Panel]

And here's the Create Droplet dialog:

[image: Droplet Dialog]

The droplet is an executable. Drop a set of files on it and the Action will run automatically as a batch.

If you set these up like this, you'll never see a Save or Save As dialog.

Comment: Yes the settings are sticky as a default, but I still have to click/confirm before saving. My images are separated into folders for compositing & organization, I'm close-cropping detailed images so a couple extra clicks to save the image to the same folder in automated actions process really does become annoying selecting folders & clicking confirmation dialogues for some folder. I can't control output folders as expected w/ Actions (the action saves the location for all output to one location), I want to save it to the original opened image's folder. Dr. Browns services?! Sounds promising!

Comment: Man, you are doing things the hard way! Actions allow you to override the Save location in the original recording so that the file saves back to its own location. I've added the links to the answer.

Comment: LOL, to you it's the hard way, to me it's the most optimal way based on circumstances I won't even go into. Believe me, I have been using actions to simplify the process as much as possible already. The override of Saving to a different output folder other than initially recorded is fine, but I have to interact to choose the correct folder again. If I open image A in folder A and record the action to PNG it and save it to folder A, then open image B in folder B and run the action, it saves to folder A - not B.

Comment: Furthermore, if I select to override the Save step in the action, then run the action on image B that means a window will pop up and ask me where to save image B -- I don't want that. I should be able to set a variable saying: [Save to folder of this open image] -- Photoshop does NOT do this or provide the option in the Actions panel.

Comment: You don't have to activate the Save dialog. I use this workflow for video screen grabs that need to be corrected for aspect ratio and saved out. Dig in on that help page and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Yes I do have to activate the save dialogue, or else the image will save to the initial folder that was recorded and not the folder that I opened the current image from. I've read help about this, and I've tested this .. it does not do what i want.

Comment: You need to set this up correctly for it to work. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Batch command worked, with some pre-planning. I think I have a process down now that incorporates what you expanded on. Thank you.